# Serializing and stringifying an error object nodejs

Tags: node.js, logging, error-handling, nestjs, pm2

I'm having this unknown error pop up occasionally during production when this API is called.

Given this simplified api(using Nest.js):

```
@api 
async blabla(@Req() request: Request) {
   try {
      //a few services doing their thing.
   } catch (e) {
     serializeErrorMethod(e)
     throw e
   }
}

serializeErrorMethod {
  const keys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(error);
  let serializedError;

  try {
     serializedError = JSON.stringify(error, keys);  
  } catch (error) {
     serializedError = {
       message: error.message || "", 
       stack: error.stack || "",
       data: (error.response && error.response.data) 
 ? error.response.data : "",        
       status: error.status || "",
       name: error.name || "",    
     }
  }    

  return serializedError;
}
```

So i tested ny code and if the error is a caught exception, it has the stack, message, trace, statusCode keys etc and it serializes beautifully. Similar with uncaught error like reading something of undefined, it captures that and has the trace property. SO i get something like this:

{stack: "bla bla bla bla"}

But for some reason, during production, this particular error happens and it cant serialize it.
I get something like this: {requestError: {}}. When i use Logger.debug(error) or Logger.debug(serializedError), this gets output to a pm2 log text file, I get [Object object].

One idea i have is to place a console.log(error) and monitoring the server and trying to catch it when the error happens but Im sure this is the worst way possible.

Apart from this, are there any other ways? Maybe a way to serialize the error entirely? I've tried serialize-error library but cant seem to get it to work due to commonJs module issue. Can't really change the existing module type of my code so looking for another alternative.